# Merge different database in different schema PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

We currently have a multi-tenant application.

Each "module" has a database for each tenant.

I'm looking for a safe way to merge (queries) to merge them in a single database per tenant, with each module its own schema.

So :

```
db module1_tenantA (schema public)
db module2_tenantA (schema public)
db module3_tenantA (schema public)
db module1_tenantB (schema public)
db module2_tenantB (schema public)
db module3_tenantB (schema public)
```

Would become :

```
db module1_tenantA (schema public) -> db tenantA (schema module1)
db module2_tenantA (schema public) -> db tenantA (schema module2)
db module3_tenantA (schema public) -> db tenantA (schema module3)
db module1_tenantB (schema public) -> db tenantB (schema module1)
db module2_tenantB (schema public) -> db tenantB (schema module2)
db module3_tenantB (schema public) -> db tenantB (schema module3)
```

What would be to best way to reach that goal? Using query or command-line.

Thanks!

Comment: Are these database running on the same cluster? Do you need to do the migration on a live system?

Comment: [`ALTER SCHEMA … RENAME`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterschema.html) and [`pgdump`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html) should be able to do it

Comment: They are on the same PSQL server instance. We can take the application offline during the migration.